# Free blogger backup too for mac

Tags: backup

I just created a blog on blogger and I'm wondering if there's any kind of tool I can use to backup my blog contents.  I'm not too worried about blogger going down, but I'd like to have a backup of my contents just in case.  Are there any good backup tools for the mac that I could use to download and back up the blog contents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hadn't tried this myself, but I've heard others recommend it.  [Backupify](http://www.backupify.com/) will allow you to sign-up for a free account until January 31.  They offer a free version which I was told stores the file on your machine, or you may choose to store your backup on Amazon's S3 for the normal S3 prices.  I need to sign-up for an account myself to backup my online information.

I hope I heard correctly and this works out for you.

Comment: looks interesting.  Not seeing an option to save the backups locally, but since it's free right now it's worth a shot.

Comment: That looks interesting, however I don't think I am going to trust them with my Gmail password.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use an rss reader and have it retain the info indefinitely even comments. This would probably be the easiest way.